# what softwares do i need to install in client computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have made a software in visual studio. now it has been completed. it uses crystal report and sql server in the backend. My question is what should I do to give this software to the actual user. I mean what softwares should be installed in the client comp and how should I deliver the software

Comment: .net framework and sql server. Then just copy the release folder inside the project.

Comment: what about the database that I created in sqlserver

Comment: you will restore that database in destination sql server

Comment: ok so I would need to download and install whole sql management studio or some other file would do the work

Comment: Management studio is just a by product. You install sql server, not ssms. Its just present within it.

Comment: Feel sorry for the client..

Answer (score -1):

Your application might work out of the box with Windows 10, but might require some additional installs with Windows 7. And might be compleatly broken with Windows 8.1.
To make sure that application will work fine, you should create the same environment that your clien would have and try to install and launch your application. You can use, for example, Hyper-V to create as many virtual PCs with as many different cases and scenarios as you can think of.
For example, you might want to create following VMs: Windows 7, Windows 7 with Office 2010, Windows 7 with Office 2013, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 with Office 2016, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question

Comment: thanks rachit I think your ans would work give it as an ans so that I can mark it right